# How to have unique suggestion on input in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to get suggestions from input box, but if model has multiple values in wheelName like "wheel1", "wheel1", "wheel2", and with this, when I enter "wheel1" in inputbox, i get 2 suggestions as wheel1, wheel1, but i want unique suggestion i.e. wheel1 to be shown only once.

Input declaration looks like below:-

```
<Input
            id="wheelInput"
            type="Text"
            placeholder="Enter Wheel..."
            showSuggestion="true"
            maxLength="40"
            startSuggestion="3"
            suggestionItems="{wheel>/results}" >
            <suggestionItems>
                <core:Item text="{wheel>wheelName}"/>
            </suggestionItems>
        </Input>
```

Comment: You can specify your own [function](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html#event:suggest) to handle the shown `suggestionItems`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your results list differs with every character you type into your input, you can attach a function to the liveChange of the Input field.

You can then put your custom logic (e.g. no double names) into a separate model property. I haven't tested the code but Ii should work (provided I didn't make a typo).

View:

```
<Input
            id="wheelInput"
            type="Text"
            placeholder="Enter Wheel..."
            showSuggestion="true"
            maxLength="40"
            liveChange="filterWheelList"
            startSuggestion="3"
            suggestionItems="{wheel>/filteredWheelList}" >
            <suggestionItems>
                <core:Item text="{wheel>wheelName}"/>
            </suggestionItems>
        </Input>
```

Controller:

```
   filterWheelList: function(){
    var wheelModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("wheelModel");
    var wheelList = wheelModel.getProperty("/results");
    var uniqueNames = [];

    var filteredWheelList = wheelList.filter(function(wheel){
    if (uniqueNames.indexOf(wheel.wheelName) === -1){
    uniqueNames.push(wheel.wheelName);
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    });

    wheelModel.setProperty("/filteredWheelList", filteredWheelList);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, was looking if some property SAPUI5 provides out of the box, but from your comments looks like we will have to get our hands dirty.

Comment: @Rahi there is a [setFilterFunction](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html#setFilterFunction) which you could check out, but you will still have to write custom logic for removing the doubles. Please let me know if you get it to work!

Comment: Works for me on a single field suggestion. However, I am filtering on two fields contact name + company and I am wondering how I set it up so that `org: [{name: "ACME Inc", contact: "Mr Jones"}, {name: "Coyote Inc", contact: "Mr Jones"}]` does not fail to recognise the second Mr Jones. I will raise another question linking to this.

Comment: Found answer to how to suggest only unique matches, or compound + unique filters. Answer is to use the uniqueNames[] technique AND pass in a blank model node attribute name to the first param of the filter constructor  e.g. `new sap.ui.model.Filter("", function(oNode) {...` this then passes the entire node into the custom filter function as param1 then you can test oNode.field1 + oNode.field2 instead of only the field passed into the constructor. Did not raise another question - sorry.